# Fully connected layer in java, Tensorflow

Tags: java, tensorflow

How to make Fully Connected Layer with Tensorflow in Java?

From their "[Keynote (TensorFlow Dev Summit 2017)](https://youtu.be/4n1AHvDvVvw?t=3m36s)" speaker I was under the impression that you can programm Tensorflow in JAVA.

From their [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/package-summary) I'm unable to find support for it. The documentation leads me to believe that I can only import models.

Answer (score 1):

The TensorFlow Java API is most suitable for importing and executing models. It does have support for building graphs of TensorFlow operations but doesn't have much of the higher level convenience APIs that Python has (layers library, estimator classes, optimizers etc.). So, in general I would recommend building the graphs in Python and then importing them into your Java application.

That said, if you did really want to build the graph, take inspiration from how the label image sample [builds a "model" for normalizing the image](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java#L74).

A fully connected layer would involve a matrix multiplication, bias add and activation function, so you'd have to add those operations into the graph. Unfortunately, yes, at this time figuring out all this isn't easy. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7149 should help - in that there would at least be generated code and documentation for all the TensorFlow operations. However, that hasn't been resolved yet.

Hope that helps.